# echo key value from a row before postgres php while loop

Tags: php, postgresql

Can't believe this is giving me a problem but here it is. An example of the query and code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        o.order_id, o.order_number, o.broker_id, o.agent_id
        FROM orders o";

$sql_res = safe_query($sql);

/* I want to echo broker_id and angent_id only once here,
   before the while loop, because the values are all the same */

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_res)){

    echo $order_number;

}
```

Assume broker and agent id numbers are each the same in every row. I don't want to echo them every time in the loop. I just want them to echo one time before the loop. Since they are the same, it does not matter which row they are echoed from.

Comment: Provided I understand the question, you could probably add `DISTINCT` in the front or use `LIMIT 1` at the end *(I am not sure if the syntax is the same for postgresql as it is for mysql but there should be a similar syntax)*. If you do it this way, your loop should only produce one row.

Comment: I provided a skeleton version of the query. Essentially, I can't change the query. My need is to echo the broker and agent id before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a different way for a means to an end. It works well.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    o.order_id, o.order_number, o.broker_id, o.agent_id
    FROM orders o";

$sql_res = safe_query($sql);

$count = 0;    

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_res)){

if ($count == 0) {

    echo $broker_id;
    echo $agent_id;

}

echo $order_number;

$count += 1;

}
```

I realize I'm echoing the broker and agent IDs inside the while loop, but it's only an echo the first time through, and I can display them at top. And then every unique order is echoed. Visually, it accomplished what was needed for the end user.